# Hierarchy Nested Dictionary to create new feature

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, nested

Have some raw data like below, it is directly come from the Mongo database and I select one row to paste here. What I need to do is to flatten it and create new feature column called `new_date` from the `'DUE_DATE'` hierarchy in python, do not know how to begin, any one has any idea. Previously try the `json.load()`, `json.normalize()`, etc. but cannot work, wondering if it is not the json object.

```
a:1:{s:6:"update";a:1:{s:8:"DUE_DATE";a:1:{s:3:"new";s:10:"2020-07-10";}}}
```

Comment: What you have given as a sample is not a well formed javascript object. Please provide a real object.

Comment: it is directly from the database and I copy and paste one row from it. Not sure what kind of object you need.

Comment: What kind of database did you extract this from? Mongo?

Comment: yes, it is from mongo

Comment: it seems the record is an oplog serialized as a string. You should try to reach who wrote to the db so it tells you what is the encoding/serialization being done. Most likely there exists the deserialization somewhere...